# SQL Managed Instance Making Connectivity Easier for Users

Tags: sql, dns, azure-sql-managed-instance

So we just switched to SQL Managed Instnace. As much as it pains me, we had more than a few places where untrained users were querying our production database(s). The switch to a business critical SQL Managed Instance was made partially because we could have them connecting to a read-only-replica of the DB.

Upon digging more, it seems that to connect to the read-only-replica (ror), they're going to need to open SSMS, hit "Advanced Options" then go over to extra parameters and put ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly. This is a bit of a bummer because 1. That means that many of them will probably mistakenly connecto to the "real" db and potentially cause havoc and 2. Thats a lot of extra steps for a user.

My Questions:

1. Is there a way to use SSMS to bake a connection into their system somehow that automatically sets the paramaters?
2. If not, is there a way to deny them connection if they DONT Have those parameters?
3. Side Note: I put a CNAME in my private DNS to cname sqlprod01.mydomain.com to the endpoint I get "bad login" but when i keep that same login info and hit the endpoint directly, it works fine. What's up with that?

Comment: A solution for untrained users is to train them. Write a **How-To** document with pretty pictures and details. Include a section on how to solve problems. Then only give them the replica endpoint.

Comment: "Only Give them the replica endpoint" -- That's my problem. The replica and non-replica endpoints are the same. You access one by adding the arguements and you access the other by ... not doing that. 

I would love if there was a way to deny them access to the non-replica endpoint in Sql Managed Instance